# Hashing a string as Firebase Auth password

Tags: node.js, firebase, hash, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a user login with Firebase Cloud Functions, but `admin.auth()` does not have any sign in method. So I decided to hash an input password and check if it's the same as that user account's password. When you do this:

```
exports.loginWithEmailAndPassword = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(req.query.email)
    .then((userRecord) => {
        const user = userRecord.toJSON();
        res.send(userRecord.toJSON())
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).send(error);
    })
})
```

The server response while entering a user email is this:

```
{
    uid: [USER UID],
    email: [USER EMAIL],
    emailVerified: false,
    disabled: false,
    metadata: {
        lastSignInTime: "Tue, 16 Jul 2019 15:05:14 GMT",
        creationTime:"Tue, 16 Jul 2019 15:04:28 GMT"
    },
    passwordHash: "UkVEQlNURUQ=",
    tokensValidAfterTime: "Tue, 16 Jul 2019 15:04:28 GMT",
    providerData: [
        {
            uid: [USER EMAIL],
            email: [USER EMAIL]
            providerId: "password"
        }]
    }
}
```

I **think** that `passwordHash` is the password string hashed, so to login I will hash an input string (password) and check if the hashed input equals to `passwordHash`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client SDK in a Node.js server environment (from within a Cloud Function) to login a user just like you do it client side on a browser.

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/auth';

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey,
});

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.query.email, req.query.password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // User successfully signed in.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error signing in.
  });
```